# How to retrieve records for a given date (regardless of time) using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I'm trying to retrieve sum of a record stored in an Access table like this

```
string query = "SELECT SUM(TOTAL) AS Expr1 FROM tblTicket WHERE (DATE_SALE = @date)";

try
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dt.Date);
    maxid = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    conn.Close();
}
```

It does not showing any data however the records have the selected date. The data is stored in  `SALE_DATE` column like this `8/27/2014 5:35:56 PM` and the `dt` object gets value from a DateTimePicker.

Comment: It is working on ms-access? What is the value of `dt.Date` exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül during debug I'm getting this one '8/27/2014 12:00am'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated that SALE_DATE has a time component. That is most likely why your where clause is not matching. I suggest using DateDiff like this:

```
WHERE DateDiff("d",@MyDateParameter,[DATE_SALE])=0
```

DateDiff will return 0 if the @MyDateParameter and [DATE_SALE] are on the same day regardless of differences in time.

> If you are dealing with a large dataset, and your query runs "slow" when using this technique, check out Gord Thompson's answer.

Comment: @jereyCook Respected Sir! where I put this Code?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show that the code goes in your WHERE clause.

Comment: cc: @Polowing - Note that this approach is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), forcing a table scan that can degrade performance as the table grows. I have posted a sargable alternative in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using `... WHERE DateDiff("d",[MyDateParameter],[DATE_SALE])=0` is that the expression is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and the database engine would be forced to do a table scan even if there was an index on the [DATE_SALE] column. A better (sargable) approach would be something like:

```csharp
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = 
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = 
                "SELECT SUM(TOTAL) AS Expr1 FROM tblTicket " + 
                "WHERE DATE_SALE>=? AND DATE_SALE<?";
        DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;  // date selected
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dt);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dt.AddDays(1));
        Object returnedValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (DBNull.Value.Equals(returnedValue)) returnedValue = 0;
        this.textBox1.Text = returnedValue.ToString();  // display result
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, so many people fall over when understanding dates with times - people forget that you want a whole day, so `>= "start of the day" AND < "start of the next day"` is the best option, especially if you want a sargable query. +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you're query to

```
string query = "SELECT SUM(TOTAL) AS Expr1 FROM tblTicket WHERE (DATE_SALE = ?)"
```

You can still add the parameter with @Date if I'm not wrong. As far as I can remember it's all position based.